# how, if at all, can I get powershell to display system drivers? (like those msinfo32 shows - the sys files)

Tags: drivers, powershell

how, if at all, can I get powershell to display system drivers? (like those msinfo32 shows)

For example

[image]

I have tried this command

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion, DriverName

DeviceName                                                                       Manufacturer                   DriverVersion   DriverName
----------                                                                       ------------                   -------------   ---
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
Local Print Queue                                                                Microsoft                      10.0.18362.1
```

But it doesn't display any driver names.. and I don't see any of those sys files that msinfo32 shows.

And I tried

`Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All`

so, `Get-WindowsDriver -Online -All >b.b`

I see lots of .inf files

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> type b.b | select-string "Driver " | select-string "\.inf"
```

But no .sys files

**added**

a commenter asks what if I use FriendlyName in the header. I see three sys files but nowhere near as many sys files as what msinfo32 shows. And it is an administrative powershell window.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion, DriverName, FriendlyName >a.a
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> type a.a | select-string "\.sys"

DriverName    : HdAudio.sys
DriverName    : HdAudio.sys
DriverName    : USBAUDIO.sys


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

a commenter suggests removing the select(though the select is only formatting so shouldn't make a difference especially since i'm filtering with pipe to look for things).

indeed, still, just three sys files

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver >a.a
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> type a.a | select-string "\.sys"

DriverName              : HdAudio.sys
DriverName              : HdAudio.sys
DriverName              : USBAUDIO.sys


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: What happens if you use FriendlyName among the selected headers?

Comment: from `Get-Help Get-WindowsDriver` >>> `NAME Get-WindowsDriver SYNOPSIS     Displays information about drivers in a Windows image.` <<< ///// so that aint gonna give you what you want. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey well the other command I tried didn't work either `PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion, DriverName`

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio just tried added to my question., no luck.

Comment: @barlop - so, given how the PoSh display system re-arranges property names ... what happens if you lave off the `Select-Object` & get the whole list of properties?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey just added to my question, no that doesn't do it

Comment: @barlop - ah! thank you for that info [*grin*] ... i will go back to lurking since i am out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the
[driverquery](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/driverquery)
command to query all drivers.

An example PowerShell command:

```
driverquery.exe /v /fo csv | ConvertFrom-CSV | Select-Object 'Display Name', 'Start Mode', 'Paged Pool(bytes)', Path | Out-String -Width 4096 >C:\Temp\mylist.txt
```

Comment: thanks.. is there something funny with your syntax after select-object. You have one backtick and no other backtick, and you aren't looking to escape something with it.  The command gives an error but works if I remove everything after ConvertFrom-CSV

Comment: Somehow copy-paste changed some of my quotes to back-quotes. Fixed.